# How to catch authentication error with SNMP4j sendtrap

Tags: authentication, snmp4j

With SNMP4j send trap I am not able to catch the Authentication Failure.

With SNMP4j send trap I am not able to catch the Authentication Failure when I use Snmp.send(pdu, uTarget);
I get a null response if i give wrong password.
I tried even using
Snmp.getMessageDispatcher()).addAuthenticationFailureListener(....)
Anyone who has achieved catching auth errors please inform. Thanks.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).